# App crashed on 10.7 lion wors fine on 10.5 and 10.6

Tags: objective-c

I have a very strange problem and no idea what creates it nor how to solve it.
The app works fine under 10.5 and 10.6.

Under 10.7 the app start fine but crashes after about 15 secs later without any user interaction.
In the debugger console i see Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
I made a screenshot of the stacktrace and it seems as if it has something to do with NSPersistentUI.

[image: screen shot]

So any hints and tips would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running with zombies enable, you haven't really given us enough information, I would guess you are not handling retain of objects between thread correctly, for example methods that are called by thread to get access to objects in another thread you should do a [myObject retains] autorelease] so to add the object to the calling threads autorelease pool.

Comment: What further information do you need? I am already doing everything mentioned here: http://loufranco.com/blog/files/debugging-memory-iphone.html I already tried several stuff regarding run with performance tool and couldn't find any hints that something is wrong in the programming. Plus everything works fine under 10.5 and 10.6. never noticed any crashes or bad access. so I tend to believe that it has something to do with lion and the underlying framework and not with my actual programming.

Comment: this _dyld_cxa_end_catch seems to be something internal. but i don't know if this is the actual problem. its just what the stack trace says. plus i can't find no functions or methods from my application inside the stack trace. cause my application is in fact fully loaded. it just crashes after 15 secs although no user interaction was done. its like the problem mentioned here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1193794 but i don't use  no magic mouse nor any other people experiencing this problem with my app.

Comment: Sorry what I should have said without you giving us you entire project it is hard to tell what is going wrong and all we can offer you is some techniques for trying to track down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Garbage Collector activated? Have you tried without it? I would suggest that. It is clearly MM problem and I would suggest you stick with retain/release.